# Trying not to get duplicate code when more than one variable in table entity is DBNull

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader, code-duplication, dbnull

I have this code that gets all the Orders out of the database, but the variables `ArriveTime` and `Paymethod` are nullable in the database. If `Paymethod` returns DBNull in the database I want it to become `iDeal` and when `ArriveTime` is DBNull than I want it to be `null`. How do I do this without getting duplicate codes.

Right now I can't think of another way besides putting a lot of `if`-statements in the code...

Code right now (5) = arrivetime and (8) = paymethod:

```
public List<OrderDTO> GetAllOrders()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Order]";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<OrderDTO> orders = new List<OrderDTO>();
            int orderIDindex = 1;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsDBNull(5))
                {
                    OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO
                    {
                        OrderID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["OrderID"]),
                        TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TotalPrice"]),
                        UserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]),
                        OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["OrderDate"]),
                        ArriveTime = null,
                        To_Adress = reader["To_Adress"].ToString(),
                        ItemCount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ItemCount"]),
                        Status = (OrderStatus.Orderstatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderStatus.Orderstatus), reader["Status"].ToString()),
                    };
                    orders.Add(orderDTO);
                }
                else if (reader.IsDBNull(8))
                {
                    OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO
                    {
                        OrderID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["OrderID"]),
                        TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TotalPrice"]),
                        UserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]),
                        OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["OrderDate"]),
                        Paymethod = PayMethod.Paymethod.iDeal,
                        To_Adress = reader["To_Adress"].ToString(),
                        ItemCount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ItemCount"]),
                        Status = (OrderStatus.Orderstatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderStatus.Orderstatus), reader["Status"].ToString()),
                    };
                    orders.Add(orderDTO);
                }
            }
            return orders;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good time to use the tertiary operator in C#

Comment: @Martin Ooohhh....I've used that before, I'll try it

Answer (score 2):

Move the repeated code out of the conditions

```
//...omitted for brevity

while (reader.Read()) {
    OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO {
        OrderID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["OrderID"]),
        TotalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TotalPrice"]),
        UserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]),
        OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["OrderDate"]),
        To_Adress = reader["To_Adress"].ToString(),
        ItemCount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ItemCount"]),
        Status = (OrderStatus.Orderstatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderStatus.Orderstatus), reader["Status"].ToString()),
    };

    if (reader.IsDBNull(5)) orderDTO.ArriveTime = null;        
    if (reader.IsDBNull(8)) orderDTO.Paymethod = PayMethod.Paymethod.iDeal,

    orders.Add(orderDTO);
}

//...omitted for brevity
```

If the values are used when not `DBNull` then check for the condition and provide the  appropriate value otherwise.

```
OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO {
    //...omitted for brevity

    ArriveTime = reader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(reader[5]),
    Paymethod = reader.IsDBNull(8) ? PayMethod.Paymethod.iDeal : //...parse the value,

    //...omitted for brevity
};
```

Comment: I get this weird error with the first tertiary operator. it says "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'DateTime'". But I seemed to solve it when I do `Convert.ToDateTime(null)`

Comment: Nevermind, when I try to convert it or cast it to either `DateTime` or `DateTime?` it says that `Int32` is not convertable to `DateTime`, any clue?

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai how is the date value stored in the database (for those that have values)? Also what is the data type for `Arrival` in the database and in the c# code?

Comment: `ArriveTime`, `DateTime` and nullable. `OrderDate`, `DateTime` and not nullable. And the Enums are just strings in the database. So basically `ArriveTime` and is `DateTime` in both database and c#

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai then since the code is not nullable, set it to `DateTime.MinValue` and use that as your *null* condition when checking value validity.

Comment: Oh...wait....I can't see where the error lays (somewhere in the instantiation of the `OrderDTO`), but I still get it. Which has to mean the error is somewhere else...but nothing else gets casted from `Int32` to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative way to do it more easier is to use a ORM like [dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper). You can reduce your 50+ LOC to less than 5.

With the help of dapper, all you need to do is

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString))
{
    var results = connection.Query<OrderDTO>(query).ToList();
    if(results.Paymethod ==null){
          results.Paymethod = PayMethod.Paymethod.iDeal
    }
    return results;
}
```

If `ArriveTime` is null it will be `null`. You don't have to re-assign it as null.

Comment: Using a whole external library to solve the simple issue of testing for two null database values feels like huge overkill to me

Comment: Actually to maintain the code overhaul and make it more readable, its better to use a proficient library. Remember `Don't reinvent the wheel`

Comment: The principle of what you are saying is sound, but this simple line of code does not need an external library to work: `if (reader.IsDBNull(5)) orderDTO.ArriveTime = null;`

Comment: @Martin understood, agree with you as well